# Why does flash consume different amounts of memory for creating an array and creating a class that contains an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory, memory-management

I was experimenting with finding how much different data structures in AS3 consumed memory.

I found creating a simple array object consumed 76 bytes:

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
trace(getSize(arr));
```

Whereas, creating a simple class that contained an array showed 20 bytes:

```
var t:Testing2 = new Testing2();
trace(getSize(t));
```

Here is what the class looks like:

```
package {
    import flash.sampler.StackFrame;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Testing2 {

        private var arr:Array;

        public function Testing2() {
            // constructor code
            arr = new Array();
        }
    }
}
```

I am puzzled. Why this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, [`getSize()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sampler/package.html#getSize%28%29) does not sum all references in your object - only the size of the pointer reference to your class.  It's the size of the `t` object pointer.

References inside your object are not reflected.

Example:

```
trace(getSize(t));      // 12-bytes
trace(getSize(t.arr));  // 32-bytes
```

This would help profile size of numerous instances pointing to the same memory model.

Other examples would include [`Bitmaps`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html), [`BitmapData`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html), and [`ByteArrays`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) to which `getSize()` does not reflect the memory retained by the object instance.

Using `getSize()` is good for [primitive types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7fff.html), benchmarking code to determine the most efficient object for a task.